# Upload images in laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5

I'm facing a problem in uploading images to server in laravel 5, the problem is some images uploaded normally, and other images breaks the server, and I got this message

```
       The specified URL cannot be found.
```

I'm using this route in routes.php

```
     Route::any('/{lang}/REGISTER','createAccountController@index');
```

My class is :

```
   namespace App\Http\Controllers;
   use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
   use App\User;
   use Illuminate\Foundation\Application;

    use App\Http\Requests;
    use Request;
    use Route;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Redirect;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Session;
    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Lang;
    use App\ImageCircleCrop;

  class createAccountController extends Controller
 {
    public function index($lang,Request $request){
             // process form data here
     }
}
```

I don't get any error messages in server logs, in fact, the application does not reach the controller code at all. Any help?

New Update: I noticed that the problem occurs just for png images, submitting form with file of type png make a crash on the application. The route does not work after that, and I got the message: "The specified URL cannot be found". Is it something related to the server configuration, or with laravel configration?

Comment: well, without code, nobody can help you

Comment: I put some code, is that enough?

Comment: How are you trying to upload your images?

Comment: I'm trying to upload it using api, I build it on laravel, on other server, but the application does not reach calling the api, it does not reach the controller createAccountController, I run the same application on my localhost and it works fine, but not working on production server.